# Angular Route Guard - Not redirecting to login page correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, authorization, auth-guard

I'm using a can activate guard and a Node server with JWT's. Routing during normal operation works well. However, when a token has expired and the page still exists in the browser, I'm able to click around in the angular app, though no API data exists. I've gone over my setup a few times and it looks right, but, for some reason, it's not redirecting to login when the token wither doesn't exist, or, is expired.

----- AUTH GUARD SERVICE

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthService } from "../auth/auth.service";
import { UserService } from "../user.service";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public userService: UserService, public auth: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.userService.logout();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

----- AUTH SERVICE

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { UserService } from "../user.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public userService: UserService, private _router: Router) {}

  ///// Method to check if user is authenticated (normal employees / non-admin)
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    // Get token from localstorage
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    // Check to see if token exists, if not return false
    if (!token) {
      return false;
    }

    // Decode token and get expiration date
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    const date = decoded.exp;

    // check if expiration is less than current time, if so return true
    if (date < Date.now()) {
      this.userService.setCurrentUser(decoded);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

----- BASIC ROUTE

```
{
    path: "projects",
    component: ProjectsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
```

----- USER SERVICE LOGOUT METHOD

```
 // Logout (used in navbar and by auth service)
  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem(this.TOKEN_KEY);
    this.removeCurrentUser();
    this._router.navigate(["login"]);
  }
```

All seems correct. User gets token from API, goes into local storage. On each route, token is read and date is checked, if still not expired, a true is returned, route is good. If token is expired then I call user service and the logout method. That method destroys the token, removed the currentUser property and navigates person to login page. That login page redirection isn't happening.

If I come back to the page after time has passed and the token is expired, then, I shouldn't be able to navigate between angular pages, but for some reason I am

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try to add `/` before login: `this._router.navigate(["/login"]);`

Comment: I am suspecting that the token is not cleared from `localStorage` properly. After logging out, in `AuthService` put a `debugger` or a `console.log` inside of the `if (!token)` and make sure it is being tripped. Also, in the `AuthGuardService`, put a `console.log` or `debugger` within the `if(!this.auth.isAuthenticated())` and make sure it is being tripped as well when you're not logged in and navigating around pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CanActivate with a return of true lets the user on to the routed path, returning false navigation is canceled. Checkout this [link](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

> Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a route can be activated. If all guards return true, navigation will continue. If any guard returns false, navigation will be cancelled. If any guard returns a UrlTree, current navigation will be cancelled and a new navigation will be kicked off to the UrlTree returned from the guard.

You may be expecting the logout function to take over from there, but it may not be working as you expect. Check out this write up on what to do: [link](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/11/better-route-guard-redirects/)

Also, check your code, it may need a '/' as mentioned in your comments.

```
this._router.navigate(["/login"]);


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
    // redirect to some view explaining what happened
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/notauthorized');
    return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Both comments actually helped. The /login helped first but more importantly, I began console logging to see where the router was going and found it wasn't touching some of the code. I've moved the route and destroy local storage into the router event, authentication is in service only.